# Windows 10: Possible to Create a Hotspot that Shares Another Wifi Connection using Two Wifi Cards?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hotspot

Many public Wifis require the user to verify by receiving an SMS message on a portal page, thus limiting the amount of devices a person can connect to the number of phone numbers they own. This is often problematic for me because I have three devices and only one phone number.

I am thinking of bypassing this restriction by only connecting my laptop to this public hotspot, hosting my own hotspot on the laptop (preferably using Windows 10's built-in hotspot feature), then connecting all my devices to my own instead.

I am aware that this requires two Wifi adapters, one in client mode and one in hotspot mode. I can go buy a cheap USB adapter so this is not a problem. My main concern is that Windows may not support this. So my question is:

If my laptop has two Wifi adapters `A` and `B`, can I use `A` to connect to an existing hotspot, then use `B` to share `A`'s connection as a seperate hotspot? Does Windows 10 even support more than one Wifi adapters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this in my laptop, it works.

I connected to internet by my computer's own network card and share the connection as a hostspot by a USB driver.

I used the matching drivers of USB adapter and it works.

I suggest you use the matching driver of USB adapter to realize this.
Just have a try bro.

Comment: So you used the USB adapter's proprietary driver to start a hotspot correct? Have you had any success with using Windows 10's built-in hotspot feature (or equivalently, `netsh wlan set/start/stop hostednetwork` in cmd in older Windows versions)? I would honestly much prefer a Windows implementation to a proprietary one.

Comment: Yes, I used the USB adapter's proprietary driver. I am more familiar with the USB adapter's proprietary driver, so I didn't use windows 10's built-in hotspot feature.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tips. I still want to see if anyone has had success with Windows' built-in feature first.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 supports more than one Wifi adapters.
We can create the first wireless adapter to network our own laptop.
Then we create a second wireless adapter to share network with other devices of our own.

For how to create mobile hotspot and share hotspot, we can refer the following two links.

https://www.howtogeek.com/214080/how-to-turn-your-windows-pc-into-a-wi-fi-hotspot/

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-your-windows-10-pc-wireless-hotspot